# Why is there only one Battlestar Galactica tag?

Tags: discussion

The two series are very different, most importantly, exist in different universes, so why is there no a separate tags? For example; [battlestar-galactica-1978](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-1978) and [battlestar-galactica-2004](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-2004).

Some questions ([like this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/what-are-the-names-of-the-12-original-battlestars)) have several different answers because there's only one tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't have 2 tags because no one brought it up before.  I can merge the existing questions over to [battlestar-galactica-2004](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-2004).  This means they'll all show with that tag, and anyone trying to use [battlestar-galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica) will be pointed to the 2004 version of the tag, due to its popularity over the 1978 version.

> Some questions ([like this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11257/what-are-the-names-of-the-12-original-battlestars)) have several different answers because there's only one tag.

Did the 78 series have a miniseries?

Comment: Great. Also: The accepted answer pertains only to the original series -- not the reimagined one. So you tell me. I'm confused.

Comment: If separate tags and an alias are created what happens to questions about continuity across both series?  (I believe new BSG is in some sense a sequel to old BSG, although I must admit to being a bit confused about how that works and why they all have the same names.)

Comment: @Christi You'd tag the question with both tags.

Comment: @Christi "All this has happened before, and all of it will happen again." - post a question  ;)

Comment: @Christi If it's applicable to both, you'd tag both. Pretty simple :)

Comment: Was this just a proposal, or have you been busy?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Both.  I always wait a few days before enacting changes like this, so as to ensure others get feedback in.

Comment: Prepare for the influx of miss-tags, especially if you're giving the most popular series the *derivative* tag. I'd have gone the way of Netflix, tagged old Battlestar Galactica simply [tag:battlestar-galactica-classic]

Comment: So... It's been over a month now. Any closer to doing something about this? :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Thanks for the reminder.  *Waves magic wand*

Comment: Cool... but -- http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/battlestar-galactica-2004/synonyms ?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt What about it?

Comment: So we're using [tag:battlestar-galactica-1978] to refer to the original series, I guess? I think I just realised what @Christi's point was.

Answer (score 7):

After thinking on this, I don't like my previously-suggested course of action.  BSG at this point is essentially a franchise composed of:

- The original '78 series
- BSG 1980
- The reimagined '04 series + its attendant movies
- Caprica
- Blood and Chrome

I think we should leave [battlestar-galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica) as a franchise tag, an umbrella tag that can be used with all of the above works.  Then each individual work should get its own tag:

- [battlestar-galactica-1978](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-1978)
- [battlestar-galactica-1980](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-1980)
- [battlestar-galactica-2004](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-2004)
- [caprica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caprica)
- [blood-and-chrome](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-and-chrome)

And then questions could be tagged with work-specific tags as appropriate.  The obnoxious part here is that this means a bunch of retagging needs to happen to enact this.

Comment: Wait wait wait 1978 and 1980?  I thought there was only one series before the 2004 reimagining!  ~goes off hunting~

Comment: @Izkata Don't get your hopes up, everything I've heard is that 1980 is an abomination. >_>

Comment: Marty Stu fanfic ahoy!  `Commander Adama and Colonel Boomer — now second-in-command — on the advice of Doctor Zee, a teenage prodigy serving as Adama's counsellor, sends Captain Troy, who is the adopted son of Adama's own son Apollo, and Lieutenant Dillon to North America, where they become entangled with TV journalist Jamie Hamilton.`

Comment: I agree with the separation of BSG 04, Caprica and Blood and Chrome, though: They're entirely different shows with different lead characters. I guess it's the same for BSG-78 and BSG-80.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of an overarching "franchise" tag, though. Does Star Trek have one?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt [tag:harry-potter], [tag:star-trek], [tag:star-wars], [tag:stargate], [tag:alien-franchise], etc.

Comment: @Keen Everyone one of those examples takes place in a single, canonical, universe. (I'm not sure why I thought to ask about Star Trek, now that I think about it, as there isn't a split canon there, either.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt The 2009 *Star Trek* is sort of a split canon.

Comment: I think if there is "overarching franchise" tags, they should reflect the two universes: Original and Reimagined. BSG: Reimagined, Caprica and Blood and Chrome all take place in the same universe. BSG: Original and BSG: 1980 take place in the same universe.